# Remove X-Powered-By:express response header from Angular UI navigation URL

Tags: angular, express

While navigating the application not getting the header x-powered-by in response headers and it is working as expected.

The problem is when a user refresh the page then the response header is getting appended with the x-powered-by header if we see in developer tools under network.

I want to remove the x-powered-by header from the response headers while navigating or browsing or refreshing to any url of application.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by disabling it: `app.disable('x-powered-by');`

Or you could use helmet: https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet#helmet